# How do you filter based on css class in Angular.js?

Tags: css, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to filter my results based on a css class and can't seem to think of the easiest/best way to do that.

Here's my [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kkjoVs?p=preview)

Essentially by clicking on a link, I would like my filtered results to only show items where the "in_red" class is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering by class, filter by the actual property of the object. After all the class *is* set based on the name property.

One solution would be to use a custom filter function:

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:filterFriends"
```

Where filterFriends would be something like:

```
function(friend) {
  if ($scope.filterOnRed === true) {
    return friend.name.substring(0,1) == 'J';
  } else {
    return friend.name.indexOf($scope.searchText) != -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's what I needed.  I needed some more work on this because I was going after the index as well and since I can't get the index inside of the function (at least I couldn't figure that out) I had to add an index element to my "friend" object and then I was able to reference it. Thanks again.